# On iPad, how to organize Shows in a native Video player app

Tags: itunes, video, ipad, group

On a computer, in iTunes I add a number of video files that I group by marking them as TV Shows. The shows, in turn, have files grouped into seasons.

When I transfer files to an iPad, I only see the Season number in the native Video app. It would be logical to at least show a show name and a season number. So if I add two different shows to an iPad, and both of them have season 1, the in Video app on the device I get two Season 1 enters on the initial screen. I can only see the name of the show if I select one of these "season 1" entries.

So my question is: is there a way for me to group files in ipda, so that I get a name of the group displayed? It doesnt necceseraly has to be shows, as long as there is grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I can't get the name of the show to come up in iPad's show list. The only way to differentiate is to get a readable album art with the show name and apply it to all seasons. This way I know what show I am clicking, as well as what season.